# Copy html from multiple <pre> tags to clipboard

Tags: javascript, html

I have several pieces of HTML within [pre] tags that I want to associate to a copy button with class 'bla'. My JS code below works for one [pre id="copyCodeOne"] BUT I need to copy several independently.. so [pre id="copyCodeTwo"]; [pre id="copyCodeThree"] etc .. What do I need to change on my JS below please?

Many thanks in advance.

```
// HTML
<code>
<pre id="copyCodeOne">
any html here
</pre>
</code>
// END HTML

// JS
var bttn = document.getElementsByClassName("bla");
for(var i = 0; i < bttn.length; i++) {
  bttn[i].addEventListener('click', copyFunction, true);
}

// Copy code to clipboard
function copyFunction() {
  const copyText = document.getElementById("copyCodeOne").textContent; // >>> I need several of these
  const textArea = document.createElement('textarea');
  textArea.textContent = copyText;
  document.body.append(textArea);
  textArea.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
};
// END JS
```

Comment: Maybe give them a class name so you can select them all?

Comment: How is the button related to the pre? COuld use a relationship to get the relate element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Select by index

Use the index of the button to selected your pre elem like so :

```
<pre>
any html here
</pre>
```

```js
function addListeners() {
    const btns = document.getElementsByClassName("bla");
    for(var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
        btns[i].addEventListener('click', (e) => copyFunction(i), true); // call function with idx 
    }
}


function copyFunction(idx) {
  // use idx to select right 'pre' tag
  const copyText = document.querySelectorAll('pre')[idx].textContent;
  const textArea = document.createElement('textarea');
  textArea.textContent = copyText;
  document.body.append(textArea);
  textArea.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
};
```

##### [Here is a working Stackblitz.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-wxamvd?file=index.html,index.js)

**Note:** If you get 'cannot read textContent of undefined' it probably means that your 'pre' elems doesn't exist, or that you have more pre than buttons elements.

Cheers

Comment: Hi, many thanks for taking the time to help! I believe btn.lenght; should read btns.lenght BUT even with that corrected I get an error: 'Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'textContent')' ...?

Comment: You're welcome, .lengths dosent exist btw. What error do you face now ?

Comment: same: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'textContent')

Comment: @riospereira I've updated my answer with a Stackblitz

Comment: Hi again, now that we have - const btns = document.querySelectorAll('button') and also the btns[i].addEventListener('click'.......,  How can I change the innerHTML of <button>A</button> when clicked to <button>Clicked!</button> ..?

Comment: Hi, you're welcome. To do so, change this line in the copyfunction : `document.querySelectorAll('pre')[idx].innerHTML = 'my text'` and remove everything else

Comment: not exactly what I wanted but it works like this: document.querySelectorAll('button')[idx].innerHTML = 'my text'; Thanks again! :)